# Полное руководство, список книг и материалов по Rust

Tags: книги, rust

Мне бы хотелось собрать практическое руководство, материалы, книги, которые смогли бы помочь мне в изучении языка **Rust**. В данный момент изучение `Rust` протекает вместе с книгой:`Программирование на Rust`,*Стив Клабник/Кэроль Николс*.
Возможно не прав, но ощущение, что у **Rust** огромная кривая обучения, либо я пока слишком глуп для изучения этого **ЯП**.

Подобный вопрос есть и по **C++**. Вот ссылка -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list .
Давайте соберем что-то аналогичное и для **Rust**.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1501087/

Comment: полетели... rustlings, курсы от jetbrains. позже надо добавить ссылки, а также собраться и написать все в ответе!