# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Rust

Tags: книги, rust, faq

В этом вопросе собирается литература и другие учебные материалы по языку Rust.

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте существующий.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги. (когда она будет)

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Официальные ресурсы:

- [Книга на официальном сайте](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) и [её перевод](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/)

## Книги для изучения Rust:

- Тим Макнамара (Tim McNamara) — «Rust в действии», 2022 ("Rust in action", 2021)
- Клабник С., Николс К. (Steve Klabnik, Carol Nichols) — «Программирование на Rust», 2021 ("The Rust Programming Language", 2021)
- Jim Blandy, Jason Orendorff, Leonora F.S. Tindall — «Programming Rust. Fast, Safe Systems Development», 2021.
- Paul Johnson, Vesa Kaihlavirta — «Learning Rust», 2017.
- Jim Blandy — «Why Rust?» 2015.
- Vigneshwer Dhinakaran — «Rust Cookbook».
- Carlo Milanesi — «Beginning Rust: From Novice to Professional» 2018.
- Jan Hohenheim, Daniel Durante  — «Rust Standard Library Cookbook» 2018.

## Веб:

- Bastian Gruber — «Rust Web Development», 2022 г.

Comment: Нашёл Bastian Gruber — «Rust Web Development» только на `manning.com/books`, - дают почитать малую часть, - потом текст в артефактах. Где-то ещё есть?